# Handling fixed-length records with embedded unix newlines

Tags: regex, perl, newline

I am receiving a text files that is fixed length fields and carriage return/newline delimited records (`CRLF`). Recently one of the text fields started to present with a newline character in the record (`LF`). This is obviously causing some problems on our unix server.

I would like to simply look for the use of `LF` in the file and replace it with a single space, but this will obviously interfere with the windows newlines.

I have tried `tr` and `perl` but can't quite seem to get it right:

```bash
cat badinput.txt | perl -p -e 's/\x0D\x0A/\x0D/' | perl -p -e 's/\0A/ /' | perl -p -e 's/\x0D/\x0D\x0A/' > goodoutput.txt
```

The idea is to

- replace `CRLF` with `CR`
- replace `LF` with
- replace `CR` with `CRLF`

For some reason I'm not quite getting the CR -> CRLF transformation.

Suggestions?

Comment: When you remove the LF, the lines ending with CR will be overwritten by subsequent lines when reading in line-by-line mode. You need to slurp the file.

Comment: Not really an answer but just say no to CSV. Every single implementation I've seen since the early 1980's has had problems due to not having a formal specification that handles issues such as in embodied in your question. Use a sane format with a formal specification such as JSON.

Comment: Use [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) if you're using perl and parsing CSV files. Instantiating with the `binary => 1` option solves this problem.

Comment: @KurtisRader , I agree ... I wish CSV would die, but after 30 years of fighting it, I'm changing tack to try to understand what makes it so good that it won't go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the whole input with `-0777` and then do the substitution:

```
perl -0777pe 's/\r\n/\r/g;s/\n/ /g;s/\r/\r\n/g' badinput.txt
```

The parameter are:

- `p` which outputs the value of `$_` at the end of each "line"
- `0777` which sets the record delimiter to undef

[Perl Command-line Options](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun)

Comment: That is a good point. When you keep CR but remove LF, then print the line, it will overwrite every line in the file except the last. Nice catch, you should add an explanation.

Comment: The new `-g` flag could do the slurping job too.

Comment: Note that -0777 doesn't set the input record separator to anything (and 0777 is a character that exists ;). It sets the value `$/` to undef.

Comment: Ah heck, I edited the answer because almost nothing you wrote was true. I left the code alone, but you didn't need to do so much work.

Comment: Oh, Jeffrey added all the bad info.

Comment: @briandfoy I was wondering how I could have missed all that strange info. "Allows multiple commands" is kind of amusing.

Answer (score 5):

Why not replace `\x0A` (with a space) when it is not immediately preceded by `\x0D`

```
s/(?<!\x0D)\x0A/ /;
```

This uses [negative lookbehind](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind)

It is probably safest to read the file into a string ("slurp" it) as it is not clear what those LF/CRLF will do for reading it "line by line" -- what is a "line" on the OS on which this is processed? So

```
perl -0777 -wpE's/(?<!\x0D)\x0A/ /g' file
```

The `0777` [command switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-0%5Boctal/hexadecimal%5D) effectively unsets the [input record separator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR).

This prints out the file with changes.  To change it in place, add `-i`.  See the linkd docs.

Comment: Another option is a short program that reads the files using `Text::CSV`, which has no problems with "embedded" newlines, and then change fields to replace `\n`.  (That can also be a "one-liner" if there is some value to that...)

Comment: Text::CSV: I'm acting as middle-man. The sender won't fix it, the import process can't handle it, so I'm purely interpretting down the middle and trying to remain unobtrusive (single bash line can be passed around)

Comment: I'm trying this regex, but its currently wiping my file. Continuing to tinker

Comment: @JeffereyCave  1) As for Text::CSV, I mean that you accomplish what you want -- remove newlines in fields. (So write it back out once that's done.) I'll add that to the post.   2) What do you mean by "_positionally delimited fields_" ... fix-length records?  (Why do you call it a "CSV"?)  3) Can you post a representative chunk of your file -- a few lines would do -- so that I can test?  Both with regex and Text::CSV.  4) What OS is this processing done on?

Comment: @JeffereyCave My test: `perl -wE'$_=shift // "A\r\nB\nc"; say; say"---"; s/(?<!\x0D)\x0A/*/; say'`  (This runs for me on two different Linux distros, perl v5.32 and v5.36.)  I can't do better without an example. In order to post a realistic Text::CSV code I also need an example.  (Are fields quoted? How are fields delimited? Perhaps it is strictly not a CSV in which case Text::CSV may not be able to help. Etc

Comment: "fix-length records" yes. I used the word "CSV" because most people I talk to don't know what a fixed length record is, but do understand the concept of a CSV. Given my solution at the time, it appeared irrelevant.

Comment: Well heck, with fixed length records I'd do something different. You can always read the next record completely without caring about the line ending because you just need a number of octets. Indeed, the idea of a line ending in fixed-length records is kinda weird.

Comment: @JeffereyCave  "_"fix-length records" yes._" -- ah, that's a different animal altogether, and there are very straightforward approaches.  (And forget about Text::CSV then.)  But what I post here should work too.

Comment: @briandfoy "_with fixed length records I'd do something different_" -- yep, same here. And it looked like it was that, which is why I asked, but I respected the prominent "CSV" in the title

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, you have records separated by a carriage-return / newline pair (and I edited your question for that). )And, update, you didn't have CSV as you said you did and fixed-length records makes a big difference. Why are there line endings in fixed-length records?) You can set the line ending to that, read one record at a time, and modify anything you like in it. You don't need `chomp` or any special line ending armor.

Here's a sample file, where there's a newline between the two `NL` literals and the line endings are CRLF (although Stackoverflow won't show you that probably):

```
one,two,three
uno,dos,tress
dog,cat,NL
NL
one,two,again
```

And what it looks like (notice `4e 4c  0a 4e 4c`)

```
$ hexdump -C badinput.txt
00000000  6f 6e 65 2c 74 77 6f 2c  74 68 72 65 65 0d 0a 75  |one,two,three..u|
00000010  6e 6f 2c 64 6f 73 2c 74  72 65 73 73 0d 0a 64 6f  |no,dos,tress..do|
00000020  67 2c 63 61 74 2c 4e 4c  0a 4e 4c 0d 0a 6f 6e 65  |g,cat,NL.NL..one|
00000030  2c 74 77 6f 2c 61 67 61  69 6e 0d 0a              |,two,again..|
0000003c
```

Now I need to read this so that the line endings are CRLF. I set the special variable `$/` (input record separator) to whatever I want. Now the bare LF isn't a problem because it's just a part of line 3, and since I don't do anything to the CR, the line endings are still CRLF (which you probably won't see here):

```
$ perl -ne 'print qq($. $_) } BEGIN { $/ = qq(\xd\xa) ' badinput.txt
1 one,two,three
2 uno,dos,tress
3 dog,cat,NL
NL
4 one,two,again
```

Next I replace all NL that are not at the end of the line (so, only interior ones). This uses a negative lookahead to check for the absolute end of string: `(?!\z)`, but other sorts of patterns will work (such as [zdim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77984366/2766176)):

```
$ perl -ne 's/\xa(?!\z)/ /g; print qq($. $_) } BEGIN { $/ = qq(\xd\xa) ' badinput.txt
1 one,two,three
2 uno,dos,tress
3 dog,cat,NL NL
4 one,two,again
```

Since the `-n` is really just wrapping the argument to `-e`, I can use its starting and ending braces to open and close different things. I close off the implicit `while` myself and use the leftover implicit closing brace for the `BEGIN`. No big whoop. But, this trick doesn't work with `-p` because there is additional implicit code that perl adds.

Comment: If you use `-l` switch, you can probably skip the lookahead, as it will autochomp, and put back the line endings. E.g. `perl -ple's/\xa/ /g' badinput.txt`. Do we need to explicitly set $/? I guess it depends on which OS the command is run in.

Comment: If you want something specific, don't depend on some other accidental condition to set what you want.